# Email ticket system

Tags: php, sql, mysql

How better to refactor nested if-blocks?

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // Usage: emailhandler.php?from=<sender>&body=<body>[&to=<device>]  
    // CREATE TABLE inbox(sender VARCHAR(255), rcpt VARCHAR(255), body VARCHAR(255));
    require_once '../incl/Config.php';
    require_once '../incl/DBi.php';
    require_once '../incl/User.php';
    require_once '../incl/Utils.php';
    $db = DB::getInstance();

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Minsk');

    $dateiname = "log.txt";
    $handler = fOpen($dateiname , "w+");
    fWrite($handler , json_encode($_REQUEST)." ".date('d.m.y h:i:s'));
    fClose($handler);


    if(isSet($_GET['from']) && isSet($_GET['body']) && !empty($_GET['from']) && !empty($_GET['body'])){
        $from = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['from']);
        $body = trim($db->real_escape_string($_GET['body']));
        $body = str_replace(array('%0a','%0d'),'',$body);

        $sql= "SELECT `email`.id as id, `email`.gateway_id, `email`.user_id as user_id, `email`.ctext as ctext, `email_response`.type as response_type, `email`.order_nr, `email`.employee_nr FROM `email` LEFT JOIN `email_response` ON `email`.id = `email_response`.email_id WHERE `email`.`fon_nr` =  '$from' AND `email`.state = 'Отправлено' AND `email`.stype='основное' ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1";
        $email = $db->fetchOne($sql);
        if($email) {
            if($email['response_type'] == null) {
                $result = intVal($body);
                if($result > 0 && $result < 6) {
                    $type = 'Correct answer';
                    $pEmailCount = 1;
                    if($email['ctext'] != '') {
                        $prices = Utils::getPrices();
                        $pEmailCount = Utils::countEmail($email['ctext']);
                        $toPay = $pEmailCount * floatVal($prices['email_price']);
                        if(User::changeBalance(-$toPay,$email['user_id'])) {
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO `email`
                                (`gateway_id`, `user_id`,`stype`,`email_amount`,`text`,`fon_nr`,`state`,`source`,`order_nr`,`employee_nr`,`sent`) VALUES
                                ($email[gateway_id], '$email[user_id]','finished','$pEmailCount','$email[ctext]','$from','process','site','$email[order_nr]','$email[employee_nr]',NOW()+1)";
                            if(!$db->query($sql)) {
                                $dateiname = "log2.txt";
                                $handler = fOpen($dateiname , "w+");
                                fWrite($handler , $sql);
                                fClose($handler);
                            } else {

                                $sql = "UPDATE `email` SET `sent_last` = NOW()+1 WHERE `gateway_id` = '$email[id]'";
                                $db->query($sql);

                                $db->query("UPDATE `gateways` SET `email_per_day_actual` = `email_per_day_actual`+1 WHERE `gateway_id` = $email[gateway_id]");
                            }
                        }
                        echo 'ok';
                    }
                } else {
                    $type = 'Incorrect naswer';
                    $result = 0;
                }
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `email_response` (`email_id`,`text`,`fon_nr`,`for_user`,`type`,`result`)
                VALUES ('$email[id]','$body','$from','$email[user_id]','$type','$result')";
                $db->query($sql);
                echo 'Saved in email_response: '.$type;

            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `email_response` (`text`,`fon_nr`,`for_user`,`type`)
                                                    VALUES ('$body','$from','$email[user_id]','Duplicate')";
                $db->query($sql);
                echo 'Duplicate';
            }
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `inbox` VALUES('$from', '$from', '$body')";
            $db->query($sql);
        }
    } else {
        echo 'parameters missing!';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should reconsider how you're fetching the email body. The character count of an email could regulary exceed ~2000 characters, which would cause issues with some browsers. (See IE http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427).

POST would be a much easier method to work with, without the need of URL encoding etc too.

Comment: @Adrian that sounds like it could make a nice review... Why don't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Before addressing the main question, I'd like to address a few points:

### Adding escaped strings to SQL queries vs prepared statements

The code uses `real_escape_string()` to escape strings like the `from` and `body` fields from `$_GET` before they are interpolated in `$sql`. It would be wise to instead use a prepared statement with bound parameters. For more information on this topic see [this article](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection) written by the author of [this answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101389/1575353) [*mysqli prepared statements and mysqli_real_escape_string*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3101307/1575353).

I haven't seen the `fetchOne()` method before - I was thinking it was from the [Mysql_xdevapi extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql-xdevapi.php) but that [`fetchOne()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql-xdevapi-sqlstatementresult.fetchone.php) takes no parameters. If it is anything like mysqli then a method like [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) or [`PDOStatement::bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) can be used to bind parameters.

### calling `isset` and `empty` on the same value

This line:

> ```
>     if(isSet($_GET['from']) && isSet($_GET['body']) && !empty($_GET['from']) && !empty($_GET['body'])){
> ```

calls both `isset()` and `empty()` on those values from `$_GET`.

The [documentation for `empty()`](https://php.net/empty) states:

> #### [Parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-parameters)
>
> #### `var`
>
> Variable to be checked
>
> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means **empty()** is essentially the concise equivalent to **!isset($var) || $var == false**.

so `!empty($_GET['from'])` is equivalent to `isset($_GET['from']) && $_GET['from'] == true`

which means the calls to `isset` are redundant and can be removed.

### Date format

The date format string passed to `date()` is `'d.m.y h:i:s'`. This does not differentiate between AM and PM. In this case perhaps it would better to use the 24-hour format- `'d.m.y H:i:s'`.

### Spacing

Adhering to a standard is not required but it does help anyone reading the code. Many PHP developers follow PSRs like [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/). While it wasn't approved until 2019, [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) replaced [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) which was approved in 2012.

> ###### [4.7 Method and Function Calls](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#47-method-and-function-calls)
>
> When making a method or function call, there MUST NOT be a space between the method or function name and the opening parenthesis, there MUST NOT be a space after the opening parenthesis, and there MUST NOT be a space before the closing parenthesis. In the argument list, there MUST NOT be a space before each comma, and there MUST be one space after each comma.
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> bar();
> $foo->bar($arg1);
> Foo::bar($arg2, $arg3);
> ```

Take for example this line:

> ```
> fWrite($handler , json_encode($_REQUEST)." ".date('d.m.y h:i:s'));
> ```

There is a space after the comma and also a space before it. Idiomatic PHP code has no space before the comma separating arguments. Also the dot operator `.` is a string operator, and thus should be preceded and followed by at least one space per section [6.2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#62-binary-operators).

> ###### [6.2. Binary operators](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#62-binary-operators).
>
> All binary [arithmetic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), [bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), [logical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), and [type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) operators MUST be preceded and
> followed by at least one space:
>
> ```
> if ($a === $b) {
>     $foo = $bar ?? $a ?? $b; 
> } elseif ($a > $b) {
>     $foo = $a + $b * $c; 
> }
> ```

```
fWrite($handler, json_encode($_REQUEST) . " " . date('d.m.y h:i:s'));
```

### Appending the request variables to the log file

> ```
>    $handler = fOpen($dateiname , "w+");
>    fWrite($handler , json_encode($_REQUEST)." ".date('d.m.y h:i:s'));
>    fClose($handler);
> ```

This could be simplified using [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
file_put_contents($dateiname, json_encode($_REQUEST)." ".date('d.m.y h:i:s'), FILE_APPEND);
```

While it is more than 10 years old, it still seems relevant: According to answers to [*What's faster? file_put_contents(); fopen(); fwrite(); fclose();?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6415958/1575353) it may be slightly faster if the code does multiple writes but this is a single write so using `file_put_contents()` will typically be faster, and also more concise.

Now for the main question:

> #### *How better to refactor nested if-blocks?*

Instead of having many nested blocks, it would be simpler to “return early” - i.e. if a pre-requisite is not met then show an error and stop processing the other code. This would be simpler with the use of a function or class method.

Let’s look at the first condition:

> ```
> if(isSet($_GET['from']) && isSet($_GET['body']) && !empty($_GET['from']) && !empty($_GET['body'])){
> ```

When that condition is false then this happens:

> ```
> echo 'parameters missing!';
> ```

So that logic could be updated to use the [`exit()` function](https://www.php.net/exit) to output the message and terminate the script, so the subsequent logic is not executed.

```
if(!(isSet($_GET['from']) && isSet($_GET['body']) && !empty($_GET['from']) && !empty($_GET['body']))) {
    exit('parameters missing!');
}
```

Then the logic on the next conditional can be flipped also:

```
$from = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['from']);
$body = trim($db->real_escape_string($_GET['body']));
$body = str_replace(array('%0a','%0d'),'',$body);

$sql= "SELECT `email`.id as id, `email`.gateway_id, `email`.user_id as user_id, `email`.ctext as ctext, `email_response`.type as response_type, `email`.order_nr, `email`.employee_nr FROM `email` LEFT JOIN `email_response` ON `email`.id = `email_response`.email_id WHERE `email`.`fon_nr` =  '$from' AND `email`.state = 'Отправлено' AND `email`.stype='основное' ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1";
$email = $db->fetchOne($sql);
if(!$email) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `inbox` VALUES('$from', '$from', '$body')";
    $db->query($sql);
    exit;
} 

if($email['response_type'] != null) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `email_response` (`text`,`fon_nr`,`for_user`,`type`)
                                        VALUES ('$body','$from','$email[user_id]','Duplicate')";
    $db->query($sql);
    exit('Duplicate');
}
```

Then the indentation levels of the subsequent code can be decreased.

Comment: [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403) ...also, why are you not recommending prepared statements?  Should `'d.m.y h:i:s'` be `'d.m.y H:i:s'`?

Comment: Thanks for the tips- I have updated my answer. Initially I was aiming to not spend a whole ton of time since ["_there is no requirement that an answer is comprehensive_"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5775/120114) and bearing in mind we don't have the same amount of active reviewers, I wish it could be more like [tag:python] where 2+ answers is the norm.